# How can I copy a Google Compute Engine snapshot to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have one application that has preset of the app server installed.

I just want that be copied as an image to GCS.

I tried 'gcimagebundle' that said 'platform is not found, you can configure the platform in the python_factory.py file'.

Is there any way that I can copy my snapshot to GCS?

More Information:

```
sudo gcimagebundle   -d /dev/sda -o /tmp/ --log_file=/tmp/abc.log
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*             !!!!  WARNING: YOU ARE INSIDE LVE !!!!                      *
*IF YOU RESTART ANY SERVICES STABILITY OF YOUR SYSTEM WILL BE COMPROMIZED *
*        CHANGE YOUR USER'S GROUP TO wheel to safely use SU/SUDO          *
*                             MORE INFO:                                  *
*      http://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?lve_pam_module.html          *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
Starting logging in /tmp/abc.log
Platform is not supported. Platform rules can be added to platform_factory.py.
```

os which i used is CentOS 6

- n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.8 GB memory)
- us-central1-b
- centos-6-v20140415

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting from gcimagebundle?

Comment: Hi jterrace - I have updated the questions with the error what i am getting and the configuration of instance

Comment: I am making images with centos-6-v20140415 and I have never seen this error. Are you using a special user to run the command ? Have you enabled LVE for your application ?

Comment: Yes I have installed cPanel, had LVE and using that and I am running in the Super User Mode using sudo -s and then gave this command in GCE, It did not work

Comment: Would you be able to post   1) what's in the log file (/tmp/abc.log) ?    2) Looking at gcimagebundle and platform_factory code, its parsing /etc/redhat-release file to determine osname. Would you be able to post what's in that file as well. It should start with something along the lines of 'centos' cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a recently added capability in Compute Engine that allows you to create an image directly from a persistent disk. Please see the docs at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#creating_an_image_from_a_root_persistent_disk

If you only have the snapshot, you would have to create a persistent disk from your snapshot first, and then use the 'gcloud compute images create' command with that disk as the source-disk